# Data Provenance Disabled NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using NIFI  1.1.0 in Clustered Mode in HDF 2.1.1, and the Data Provenance is disabled, any idea how can I enable it ?

In my Standalone version it was enabled by default.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think provenance is disabled by default? It should not be and there isn't really a way to disable it.

Comment: I updated my post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main difference between your standalone instance and the cluster is that your cluster has been secured. Also the user you're accessing the cluster as hasn't given permission to view provenance.

In order to view provenance go to "Policies" and add your user to the "Query provenance" policy. Also you need "View the data" policy for any processor you want to view the provenance for.

After you do that you should be able to query provenance.

Comment: To add to Joe's answer -- the system is still collecting data provenance on all events even if the current user does not have permissions to view/query it.